# MariaDB - dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

Tags: debian, configuration, mysql, debian-installer, mariadb

I have tried to install ISPConfig3 on Debian Jessie 8.1, and it couldnt connect to mySQL (mariaDB 10.1). So I CTRL+C to kill the install and I tried to manually login to mySQL, but I failed. It was complaining about the socket. So I purged and removed mariaDB and mySQL:

```
service mysql stop
apt-get --purge remove "mysql*"
mv /etc/mysql/ /tmp/mysql_configs/
apt-get remove --purge mysql*
apt-get autoremove
apt-get autoclean
service apache2 restart
apt-get update
```

Inside the source.list I have (added last two lines) (`nano /etc/apt/sources.list`):

```
deb http://debian.mirror.constant.com/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://debian.mirror.constant.com/ jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free

deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://ftp.utexas.edu/mariadb/repo/10.0/debian jessie main
deb-src http://ftp.utexas.edu/mariadb/repo/10.0/debian jessie main
```

Then I followed the commands given by [MariaDB](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=ut-austin&distro=Debian&distro_release=jessie--jessie&version=10.0):

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 0xcbcb082a1bb943db
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
```

I get the following error:

```
Setting up mariadb-server-10.1 (10.1.9+maria-1~jessie) ...
2015-12-15 11:26:57 140472422967232 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.9-MariaDB-1~jessie) starting as process 12018 ...
2015-12-15 11:26:57 140472422967232 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'myisam_recover' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'myisam-recover-options' instead.
2015-12-15 11:26:57 140472422967232 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-12-15 11:26:57 140472422967232 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-12-15 11:26:57 140472422967232 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-12-15 11:26:57 140472422967232 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-12-15 11:26:57 140472422967232 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2015-12-15 11:26:57 140472422967232 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-12-15 11:26:57 140472422967232 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-12-15 11:26:57 140472422967232 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 256.0M
2015-12-15 11:26:57 140472422967232 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-12-15 11:26:57 140472422967232 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-12-15 11:26:57 140472422967232 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-12-15 11:26:57 140472422967232 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-12-15 11:26:57 140472422967232 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 19615081045
2015-12-15 11:26:57 140471636559616 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2015-12-15 11:26:58 140472422967232 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Job for mariadb.service failed. See 'systemctl status mariadb.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-10.1 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:
 mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-10.1 (= 10.1.9+maria-1~jessie); however:
  Package mariadb-server-10.1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server-10.1
 mariadb-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try the following:

```
apt-get remove --purge mysql*
apt-get remove --purge mysql
apt-get remove --purge mariadb
apt-get remove --purge mariadb*
apt-get --purge remove mariadb-server
apt-get --purge remove python-software-properties
```

Note: When prompted if you want to dump your current Databases, say no. But you can deconfigure the phpmyadmin database easily.

Install everything from fresh: 
Add the following to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://ftp.utexas.edu/mariadb/repo/10.1/debian jessie main
deb-src http://ftp.utexas.edu/mariadb/repo/10.1/debian jessie main
```

Then,

```
apt-get install python-software-properties
apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 0xcbcb082a1bb943db
apt-get install software-properties-common
apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-client
```

Once your are done you should be able to run `mysql -V` and see something like:

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.9-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

Comment: apt-get remove --purge mysql will remove all existing databases too ?

Comment: python-software-properties and software-properties-common have got nothing to do with mysql/maridab.

Answer (score 3):

I just got this error. For those new here.

The problem was from `mysql` database missing. Because I deleted the folders `/var/lib/mysql/` and `/etc/mysql/`.

I just executed `sudo mysql_install_db`. Then start the MySql service `sudo service mysql start`. It should work.

If you get error when executed `sudo mysql_install_db`, execute `sudo mkdir /etc/mysql/conf.d/`. Then start again.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar issue installing MariaDB server 10.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04.

```
Setting up mariadb-server-10.0 (10.0.31-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-10.0 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:
 mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-10.0 (>= 10.0.31-0ubuntu0.16.04.2); however:
  Package mariadb-server-10.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

@user3502626's answer gave a hint using `sudo mysql_install_db`, which provided a new error:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
```

Searching for that error led to [a Debian bug report that pointed the problem at AppArmor](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=865534#10), and could be solved with:

```
$ echo -n "/usr/sbin/mysqld" | sudo tee /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/.remove
$ apt install -f
$ apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

That installed MariaDB properly.

Answer (score 1):

This situation could occur if the timeout for the init script was too short. For example, see [MDEV-9382](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-9382), a situation where the timeout was 30 seconds, but the server was taking 48 seconds to start.

On systems where systemd is not enabled/supported :

> The timeout can be increased by setting MYSQLD_STARTUP_TIMEOUT either
>   directly in the script or via the command line. In MariaDB 10.1.13 and
>   later versions, the init script also sources /etc/default/mariadb, so
>   it can also be used to set MYSQLD_STARTUP_TIMEOUT to persistently
>   change the startup timeout. The default timeout has been increased
>   from 30s to 60s in MariaDB 10.1.13.

On systems that support systemd:

> The startup timeout can be increased by setting TimeoutStartSec
>   systemd option. If there are some systemd settings to override or to
>   set, create a file /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/XXXX.conf
>   file where XXXX is something meaningful to you and place the
>   configuration option(s) in an appropriate section, usually [Service].
>   If a systemd option is a list you may need to set this to empty before
>   you set the replacement values, e.g.:

```
[Service]

TimeoutStartSec=
TimeoutStartSec=60
```

After any configuration change `systemctl daemon-reload` will be required to pick up the changes.

***Source:*** https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/apt-upgrade-fails-but-the-database-is-running/

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a .my.cnf file in your home directory? This was causing the error for me. I simply delete it and restart the installation process.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

..resolved this for me

Use this with caution because `dist-upgrade` may remove a package if there's a conflict between packages or dependencies that can't be satisfied. `dist-upgrade` will tell you the list of packages that it deems fit for installation and removal. Observe the list before making changes

Credits to [Florian](https://askubuntu.com/a/215268)

Comment: It downloads something new, but not changes real version.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you didn't remove mysql completely before trying to use mariadb. So try this.

```
sudo apt remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt remove --purge mysql
sudo apt remove --purge mariadb
sudo apt remove --purge mariadb*
sudo apt --purge remove mariadb-server
```

Then try re installing it again

```
sudo apt install mariadb-server mariadb-client
```